# data.table, how to reset cumsum (or add a group to group by)

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table with some computed columns

```
dt <- data.table(x=c(1,4,-3,-2,3,4))
dt[,y:=cumsum(x)]
dt[,q:=cumsum(ifelse(x>0,x,0))]
    x y  q
1:  1 1  1
2:  4 5  5
3: -3 2  5
4: -2 0  5
5:  3 3  8
6:  4 7 12
```

What I need to do is reset q after y==0. In essence rows 1:4 belong to subgroup A and 5:6 to subgroup B. The result should be:

```
    x y  q
1:  1 1  1
2:  4 5  5
3: -3 2  5
4: -2 0  5
5:  3 3  3
6:  4 7  7
```

I guess I could introduce another column group with values A,B,... which would change after y==0 and then use that in by expession, but I don't know how (at least not other than using for clause)

Comment: how many 0 in the y column are there in the data.table?

Comment: Something like `dt[,q:=cumsum((x>0) * x), by = cumsum(y == 0)]` maybe? But I'm not sure why you want the 5 in row 4

Comment: I am kinda confused as to what you want, so you want the cumsum of 1:4, and than a new one from 5:6 ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this

```
dt[, group:= cumsum(y == 0)]
dt[y == 0, group := group - 1]
dt[, q:=cumsum(ifelse(x>0,x,0)), by = group]
dt
#   x y group q
#1:  1 1     0 1
#2:  4 5     0 5
#3: -3 2     0 5
#4: -2 0     0 5
#5:  3 3     1 3
#6:  4 7     1 7
```

Comment: I had a similar case for which this, with slight modification, worked well. Well done.

Answer (score 9):

With `data.table` devel version

```
dt[, q:=cumsum(ifelse(x>0,x,0)),by=shift(cumsum(y==0),1, fill=0)] 
#library(devtools)
#install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)
#    x y q
#1:  1 1 1
#2:  4 5 5
#3: -3 2 5
#4: -2 0 5
#5:  3 3 3
#6:  4 7 7
```

Comment: You'll need the devel version here.

Comment: Looks really interesting, but I can't use devel on this project

Answer (score 7):

You could add the condition `c(0L, cumsum(y == 0L))[-length(y)]` into the `by` statement

```
dt[, q := cumsum(ifelse(x > 0, x, 0)), by = c(0L, cumsum(y == 0L))[-length(y)]][]
#     x y q
# 1:  1 1 1
# 2:  4 5 5
# 3: -3 2 5
# 4: -2 0 5
# 5:  3 3 3
# 6:  4 7 7
```

Comment: Thanks! For now I'll stick with the more verbose implementation as I'm really just starting R